# Existence of solution for nonlinear (algebraic) equations.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

Let

$f_1(x_1,\cdots,x_n)=0$,

$\vdots$

$f_n(x_1,\cdots,x_n)=0,$

be a nonlinear equation. Is there a condition on $f_1,\cdots,f_n$ under which this equation has a solution?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: For generic $f$? Of course not.

Comment: Are you assuming that $f_1,\dots,f_n$ are polynomials? If so, then there is Hilbert Nullstellensatz: there is a solution if and only if $1\notin\left\langle f_1,\dots,f_n\right\rangle$.